# ¿Cómo podría sustituir el "column name" por su respectivo descriptivo?

Tags: r

Estoy trabajando con una serie de archivos extensión .sav, pero necesito pasarlos primero a formato csv para más adelante manipularlos desde Tableau. El inconveniente que tengo es que al cambiar el formato pierdo el descriptivo ligado a cada variable, quisiera remplazar el "column name" por ese descriptivo (en SPSS se conoce como "etiqueta") para que no queden las variables codificadas.

Por ejemplo necesitaría remplazar "ID_AMO" por "Identificador del año"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

En principio sería útil contar con una función que nos retorne este atributo, si la variable lo tiene, o un `NA` sino:

```
get_col_label <- function(x) {
  if (!is.null(attr(x, "label"))) {
    return(attr(x, "label"))
  } else {
    return(NA)
  }
}
```

Entonces suponiendo un `data.frame` con columnas con etiquetas, por ejemplo:

```
# le ponemos una etiqueta a mpg de mtcars
attr(mtcars$mpg, "label") <-  "millas por galón"
```

Podemos aplicar la función en todo el `data.frame` para obtener las etiquetas de cada columna:

```
sapply(mtcars, get_col_label) -> etiquetas
```

Y luego simplemente reemplazar el nombre de cada columna

```
colnames(mtcars) <- ifelse(is.na(etiquetas), colnames(mtcars), etiquetas)
```